# Difference between SockJS and ActiveMQ/RabbitMQ

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, sockjs

I have recently developed a simple messaging application with Spring Boot and Spring Security. The application takes in 2 users - user `A` and user `B`. Once, user `A` performs a specific task a notification is sent to user `B`. Currently I am doing this by adding a Spring Messaging dependency and SockJS and it works great.

Here is where I am confused and hoping to receive some guidance. I realize there are many tutorials that speak about RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ. From what I understand, they are message brokers. May I ask what is the difference between SockJS and RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ? And do I need RabbitMQ/ActiveMQ in my current application together with SockJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SockJS is JavaScript based WebSocket *client* library that runs in a browser. It can be used to send messages to or receive messages from a broker.

Both RabbitMQ and ActiveMQ are message *brokers*, examples of [message-oriented middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message-oriented_middleware). They both support WebSocket clients which use a messaging protocol (e.g. STOMP or AMQP). Brokers receive messages from and dispatch messages to clients.

You haven't really provided enough information to determine whether or not you actually *need* to use either RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ in your current application given that it's already working as it is.

Comment: To clarify, you mentioned 'Brokers receive messages from and dispatch messages to client'. Since, my application is about sending a notification. Does this mean that a message broker would definitely require a websocket client such as SockJS to send a message from one user to another?

Comment: Clients can use any kind of protocol that the broker supports to send messages to each other. For example, one client might be connected via SockJS & WebSocket using STOMP and another could be connected via MQTT on some IoT device and they could exchange messages.